# Telegram gives Empty reply from server while trying to send some images with cUrl

Tags: php, api, curl, multipartform-data, telegram

I made a function in php which uses multipart/form-data and cUrl to send documents via Telegram's sendDocument api. [Here is documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument)

Specifically, I use it to send .png file as documents, but it doesn't work with 2 or 3 images in total, of hundreds that were successful. The error returned by curl_error is "Empty reply from server". I dont' know why and how it comes only with those images. [Here you have one of those](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwncXt4cfJK8MmNvSmRUZkFzWUU)

This is the function I use:

```
function spng($chat_id, $nome, $fnome = 'justforwardme.png')
{
global $api;
define('BOTAPI','https://api.telegram.org/'.$api.'/');

$cfile = new CURLFile($nome, 'image/png', $fnome);
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chat_id , 
        'document' => $cfile
        ];

    $ch = curl_init(BOTAPI.'sendDocument');
    if ($ch===false) return array(false, 'Unable to set URL');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
              'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) $error = 'none'; else $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array($result, $error);
}
```